# yet another aggregation

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape

(sorry if the title is not very informative: I don't know how to define better this question)

I have my data in the following form:

[image: original data]

In each group I have one `pre` value and one or two `post` values. I would like to convert this table to the following:

[image: what I would like to get]

I was thinking to group the data with something like:

```
aggregate(mydata, by = group, FUN = myfunction)
```

or

```
ddply(mydata, .(group), .fun = myfunction)
```

and process the elements of each group in my function. But I don't see how to do this because I need to pass both `type` and `value` to my function simultaneously. Is there a better way to do this?

**Update:** quick-and-dirty sample dataset:

```
mydata <- data.frame(group = sample(letters[1:5], 10, replace = TRUE), 
                     type = sample(c("pre", "post"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
                     value = rnorm(10))
```

Comment: Screenshots are really not helpful. Can you post some sample data that we can copy-and-paste into an R session to work with.

Comment: ah, sorry, you're right. Just a second, I will attach sample data.

Comment: I would say use dcast() from the reshape2 package, but you have that nasty post2 in the C group.

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look on dcast. But, in general - there is no way to pass multiple variables of subset into the user's function? That would be much easier for me: then I would simply return a list containing "pre", "post1" and "post2" for each subset...

Comment: @VasilyA, another tip, when posting sample data that uses random number generators, do be sure to use `set.seed()` before the code. That will make it so that everyone is playing with the same data.

Comment: @VasilyA, I've edited your post to add the `aggregate` and `reshape` tags. In general, "aggregation" would involve some sort of summarizing of the data--for example, you might *aggregate* the two "post" values in group "C" by taking their sum, mean, or some other calculation. When we talk about *reshaping* data, though, we are talking about transforming how the data are presented or organized. Thus, this question isn't really "yet another aggregation", and it would be more useful if you can think of a more descriptive title to help future visitors who might have similar questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
mydf <- data.frame(group = c("A", "A", "B", "B",
                             "C", "C", "C", "D",
                             "D", "E", "E"),
                   type = c("pre", "post", "pre",
                            "post", "pre", "post",
                            "post", "pre", "post",
                            "pre", "post"),
                   value = 1:11)

times <- with(mydf, ave(value, group, type, FUN = seq_along))
xtabs(value ~ group + interaction(type, times), mydf)
#      interaction(type, times)
# group post.1 pre.1 post.2 pre.2
#     A      2     1      0     0
#     B      4     3      0     0
#     C      6     5      7     0
#     D      9     8      0     0
#     E     11    10      0     0
```

Or:

```
times <- with(mydf, ave(value, group, type, FUN = seq_along))  
mydf$timevar <- interaction(mydf$type, times)
reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", idvar = "group", 
        timevar="timevar", drop="type")
#    group value.pre.1 value.post.1 value.post.2
# 1      A           1            2           NA
# 3      B           3            4           NA
# 5      C           5            6            7
# 8      D           8            9           NA
# 10     E          10           11           NA
```

The key, in both solutions, is to create a "time" variable that is represented by the combination of "type" and a sequence variable that can be created with `ave`.

For completeness, here's `dcast` from "reshape2":

```
times <- with(mydf, ave(value, group, type, FUN = seq_along))
library(reshape2)
dcast(mydf, group ~ type + times)
#   group post_1 post_2 pre_1
# 1     A      2     NA     1
# 2     B      4     NA     3
# 3     C      6      7     5
# 4     D      9     NA     8
# 5     E     11     NA    10
```

Comment: You can wrap the output of `xtabs` in `as.data.frame.matrix` to get a `data.frame` instead. For this particular question, I prefer the `reshape` output since it presents the values as `NA`, not `0`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto why do you make a call to "with" ? wouldn't the ave call suffice ?

Comment: @AdityaSihag, that'll only work if "value", "group", and "type" are directly accessible in your current environment, which they aren't unless you have used `attach`, which I don't like to do. The other option is `ave(mydf$value, mydf$group...` which is a lot of extra typing and, thus, more error-prone.